What is the least amount of time i can own a stock to get dividend?
As we should own the stock at the close of trading on the day before the ex-dividend date,
does the extended trading close at 7:59 PM or 11:59 PM.
So buy at  7:59 PM and sell at 8:00 PM
or
buy at 11:59 PM and sell at 12:00 AM
Which of these would make you eligible for the dividend?

In case it's not clear from the duplicate, buying the stock right before the dividend and selling it right after will not mean "free money" since the stock price will drop by the dividend amount.

Well, if you can buy at 11:59 PM and sell at 12:00 AM and still collect the dividend. Then yes.

Say the stock was $100 and paid a $5 dividend. After the dividend, stock would be valued at $95 (meaning you could only sell it for $95). So you'd have a $95 stock and $5 in cash - still $100.  This is a well-established phenomenon in the stock market.

In short - as long as you hold the dividend at the end of the ex-div date, you get the dividend. It doesn't matter when you sell so long as it's after the end of the ex-div date.

So on Thursday I bought MRVL at 7:30 PM , sold at 8:30 PM and still received the dividend. So the answer to this question would be buy at 7:59 PM and sell at 8:00 PM, as the extended trading closes at 8.00 PM.

Did you sell at the same price you bought it?

Yes, same price.

That's very surprising. I suspect that either you won't actually get the dividend once it's noticed that you sold, or you got lucky and caught someone with an unadjusted buy order (meaning they paid the higher price but did NOT get the dividend).

You can see the dividend confirmation here. The price didn't move much during that period, so I was able to sell it.
https://ibb.co/GvzdRJr
